# java howto mark places using longitude and latitude on a world map

Tags: java, gps

I have a list of gps positions like this:
( not even sure they are called gps positions)

```
38.54090514, -121.76151662 
53.3661332, -1.8168501
```

Where to start reading about how to mark this positions on a world map?

Been reading allot but cannot get a grip what librarys or java classes to use.

Would be grate to get a beginner example project.

Comment: are you using google maps? check their documentation

Comment: @Adrian  The Google maps API is in javascript, not java.

Comment: you mean i can use some google map library in desktop java application

Comment: @Erik you can, I did the same thing (with Qt) in C++ (google maps, places, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it seems noone's answering.

The problem is, there's no standard API for displaying a map.

Moreover, every map comes in its own projection, be it [Mercator projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection) or something else, and in its own [datum](http://www.maptools.com/UsingUTM/mapdatum.html), be it WGS 84 used by GPS or something else (my home country happened to love the SK-42 reference system also known as the Krasovsky ellipsoid).

Now in order to put your GPS (WGS 84) position on a map, you need to know what map you have at hand, what projection it uses, and what [reference ellipsoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_ellipsoid#Historical_Earth_ellipsoids), or *datum*, was used to build that projection.

Without that, noone can help you.

Comment: would they work if you plugged the coords straight into google maps? @Erik give it a try! Maybe they will show up on the map then you know they're compatible.

Comment: @Adrian as far as I remember, Google Maps uses WGS84 datum, so putting GPS coordinates to [*.kml](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmlreference.html) should work just fine.

Comment: dunno what *.kml is must read up on that to. I try the http://maps.google.se and my above long/lat is working..

Comment: `*.kml` is a file format used by Google Maps and Google Earth; the reference in the comment above leads to the format description; the tutorials are easily searchable.

Comment: im lost, mm so you mean in my java JPanel i create a browser window for maps.google.se and input gps data into the *.kml. naaaa..dunno. sorry you guys a way above me hahahah

Comment: @Erik let's start with a simpler task: how do you show a map without any additional points? When you know the answer, we can discuss what to do further.

Comment: @alf could this be useful for me?http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/10/30/building-maps-into-swing-app-with-jxmapviewer.html

Comment: @Erik it should be; the only problem is, they do not mention the datum they use: *The GeoPosition class represents a coordinate on the globe expressed as a latitude and longitude.* — so just try. If you're lucky, and they use WGS84, you're done. If they're not, well, you'll need to experiment.